# No Activity found to handle Intent: ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm trying to start an activity for whitelisting an app on the emulator (API 25), but I keep getting an error saying:

```
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: 
No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS }
```

Here's my code:

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
    startActivity(intent);

  }
```

Anyone know why this error is thrown?

Comment: I'm not sure why it happens but as a sidenote, AFAIK your app may be suspended from Play Store for requesting `REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS`.

Comment: @LieForBananas I've looked it up, but my app takes time lapse photos so I think it falls under 'Task automation app'? https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#whitelisting-cases

Comment: I think so, but it's for Google to decide whether it's a "core" functionality or not :) just wanted to make sure :) good luck!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the Android Developer Documentation:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS

Looks like you are missing this part:

> Input: The Intent's data URI must specify the application package name to be shown, with the "package" scheme. That is "package:com.my.app"

The following line should help:

```
intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName()));
```

Comment: I have that line, but still getting the crash on some devices (Crashlytics).

Comment: The same issue appeared in my app only on Galaxy A5 devices (API 23)
I'm using the package name with package schema, but seems some devices don't handle that intent.

Comment: Cannot accept this is right answer, it was not work form me

Answer (score 0):

you should specify your package name !

```
intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
```

here is document  :

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS